# Русские ресурсы html, css, http

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, http

у меня несколько вопросов: 
1. Есть ресурс MDN очень крутой в плане английского языка, с которым у меня проблемы, хотелось бы узнать там перевод хороший или не очень на русский язык?
2. Подскажите  русскоязычные ресурсы по html, css, http кроме 
[Javascript.learn.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/) потому что там мало информации по html, css и http
3. Подскажите книги на русском языке хорошие по html, css (актуальные)

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под ресурсами по `http`? Про данный протокол можно почитать в Википедии. Если интересует работа с протоколами, то это уже немного другая степь

Comment: @L.F.C. но там ресурсы английские, а я как раз спросил про актуальные и переведённые или русские :)

Comment: webref, metanit, htmlbook, html5book -очень даже на русском. Книги там тоже подборка только переведенных и актуальных, новее не найдешь, я сам тот список делал для сообщества. Если знаешь актуальней, добавь, вопрос общий, каждый может внести свой вклад

Comment: @L.F.C. Get, Post и остальные запросы для Rest api, но и вообще про http и https прочитать и их запросы

Comment: @L.F.C. а MDN нормальный ресурс? Перевод нормальный?

Comment: MDN один из самых лучших ресурсов, но перевод на нём плохой (в основном машинный), лучше читать его на английском. Но там уровня английского достаточно pre-intermediate (т.е. достаточно низкий). Разве указанных мною 5 ресурсов мало, сколько ещё надо ресурсов на русском, 10? 20? На личном опыте, учась только по 2-вум webref и MDN, когда-то работу нашел и стал зарабатывать деньги, сейчас я уже в другой степи. Гланое учится, практиковаться и меньше говорить и рассуждать, а остальное придет. Удачи!

Comment: Вопрос, про `http`: *Get, Post и остальные запросы для Rest api, но и вообще про http и https прочитать и их запросы* - рекомендую вынести в отдельный вопрос, так как данный будет закрыт, как раз голосуют за закрытие. Да и не вяжется тут одно с другим

Answer (score 1):

У MDN перевод хороший, можете использовать. Насчет ресурсов:

> Сайты:
>
> [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru), [HtmlAcademy](https://htmlacademy.ru/)

> Книги:
>
> [Дженнифер Нидерст Роббинс «HTML5, CSS3 и JavaScript. Исчерпывающее
>   руководство». 4-ое издание (2014)](https://vk.com/wall-54530371_5940)
>
> [Дэвид Макфарланд «Большая книга CSS3» (2014)](https://vk.com/wall-54530371_1177)
>
> [Брайан Хоган «HTML5 и CSS3. Веб-разработка по стандартам нового
>   поколения» (2011)](https://books.google.ru/books/about/HTML5_%D0%B8_CSS3_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA.html?id=Sgcw0HrQ7KYC&redir_esc=y&hl=ru)
>
> [Терри Фельке-Моррис «Большая книга веб-дизайна» (2017)](https://books.google.ru/books/about/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7.html?id=d2oaBAAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)

Comment: Спасибо большое, а у книг хороший перевод? А то многие пишут что переведенные книги - плохие книги и читать их нужно только на английском, который к сожалению я только учу(

Comment: @MikeMclaren Я быстро глянул, переведены хорошо, без всяких "А сейчас, мы верстать страницу". В изучении английского — удачи )

Answer (score 1):

Ссылки на скачивание книг(из [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive)):
[Джон Даккет HTML и CSS](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wme49pcu7sN59SCzPqlv_W-WA-mT3pDI)
[Джон Даккет JavaScript and JQuery](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TZz_De7Xd6l5AcICZo8Fvs5ht_VVEAww)
1. Джон Дакетт "HTML и CSS. Разработка и дизайн веб-сайтов" [PDF]

Год: 2013 
Язык: русский

Эта книга – самый простой и интересный способ изучить HTML и CSS. Независимо от стоящей перед вами задачи: спроектировать и 
разработать веб-сайт с нуля или получить больше контроля над уже существующим сайтом, эта книга поможет вам создать привлекательный, дружелюбный к пользователю веб-контент. Хотя код веб-страниц может немного вас пугать, загляните в книгу и вы увидите, насколько это руководство отличается от большинства остальных книг по веб-дизайну. 
Простой визуальный способ подачи информации с понятными примерами и небольшим фрагментом кода знакомит с новой темой на каждой странице. Вы найдете практические советы о том, как организовать и спроектировать страницы вашего сайта и после прочтения книги сможете разработать свой веб-сайт профессионального вида и удобный в использовании. Никакие специальные навыки для освоения книги не требуются. 
Эта книга предназначена для веб-дизайнеров и программистов, контент-менеджеров и редакторов контента, маркетологов и менеджеров 
по электронным продажам, блогеров и любителей.

2. Джон Дакетт "Javascript и jQuery. Разработка и дизайн веб-сайтов" [PDF]

Год: 2017 
Язык: русский

Эта книга предназначена для веб-дизайнеров и программистов, контент-менеджеров и редакторов контента, маркетологов и т.д. Мы не только объясним вам, как читать и создавать сценарии, но также изложим основы компьютерного программирования в простой и наглядной форме. Приглашаем вас в приятное путешествие — изучение языка JavaScript и библиотеки jQuery. Вы впервые встретились с языком JavaScript или уже добавили какие-либо сценарии на свои веб-страницы и желаете лучше понять, как они устроены? Тогда эта книга для вас. Все, что вам потребуется, — это знание стандартов HTML и CSS. Эта книга научит вас тому, как сделать сайты более интерактивными, привлекательными и удобными для пользователя. Цель достигается при помощи объединения теории программирования с примерами, которые демонстрируют применение сценариев JavaScript и библиотеки jQuery на известных сайтах. Практически сразу вы сможете мыслить и создавать код как программист. Вы узнаете о том, как: 
• читать и создавать сценарии JavaScript 
• сделать ваши сайты интерактивными 
• использовать библиотеку jQuery для упрощения кода 
• применять технологии Ajax, API и JSON 
• улучшать формы и проверять данные 
• пользовтаься фильтрацией, поиском и сортировкой.
Джон Дакетт проектирует и разрабатывает веб-сайты уже более десяти лет. Он работает как с небольшими стартапами, так и глобальными брендами. Под его авторством выпущено несколько книг, посвященных 
веб-дизайну, программированию, юзабилити и доступности веб-сайтов. Его книга "HTML и CSS. Разработка и создание веб-сайтов" 
стала бестселлером в России. 
Если говорить про порталы для изучения HTML/CSS JS то, как сказал [Ver Nick](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282637/ver-nick) это:
 [htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/) и [HTML Academy](https://htmlacademy.ru/), с не менее хорошей репутацией